# counting the number of regular files and folders contained in a directory and its sub-folders

Tags: linux, shell-script

Hey I don't know why it's not working for me .. i've been searching for more than 1h and I still can't make it work

Here's what I should do

[image]

And here's what I did

[image]

It's supposed to work no ? when I submit on the site it doesn't work "FAILED" means there's an error and it's not the result that he wants.

My code : `find .-type f | wc -l`

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: Post the text, for example that allows me to copy it and try it locally.

Comment: @icarus okay sorry i just posted the text of my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `-type f` will find all regular files, but the question is asking for "all regular files and folders". To find directories as well, you'll need to add that type like so: `-type f,d`.

It's worth noting that this will also count the current directory, which the question might not want. If this is the case, you will need to set a minimum depth so that only the contents are looked at. You can do this like so:

`find . -mindepth 1 -type f,d | wc -l`

Comment: It worked well for me when I added the "d" thank you very much <3